# Mac OS X Darwin: how to reset admin password?

Tags: osx, root, startup

Today I bought an ibook G4 from a garage sale. The people who sold it to me didn't know the password for the 2 accounts on it. Apparently it was the guys late father's laptop. Any suggestions on how to get into the laptop and set a new admin account and password?

Comment: If you're able to gain access to the existent accounts using the accepted answer, I suggest you offer these guys access to their father's data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must boot the Mac into single user mode and change an admin user's password from the command line.  How to do it depends on the Mac OS version installed on the iBook.

Here are the instructions for 10.4 (Tiger) which is probably what's installed on such an old Mac:

> 1. Power on your Mac.
> 2. At the chime hold down <kbd>Command S</kbd> on your keyboard to boot into single-user mode.
> 3. Type **sh /etc/rc** and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
> 4. Type **passwd username** <kbd>Return</kbd>, replacing “username” with the short name of the account whose password you want to change.  You can get a list of account short names with **ls /Users** <kbd>Return</kbd>.
> 5. Enter the new password and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
> 6. Type **reboot** <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Once the Mac boots you should be able to log into the account whose password you changed.

Comment: I advise buying an old installation DVD and doing a complete OS reinstall at your earliest convenience.  I would not trust the existing installation to not be compromised in some fashion.